# code can't find GridView Controls

Tags: list, development, user-controls, gridview

I have some code and it is unable to take the values entered from a dropdown list or textbox and output them to a SharePoint List. here is the code

```
        try
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList List = web.Lists["FORM D List"];
            SPListItem NewItem = List.Items.Add();
            string title = "this is new";
            NewItem["Title"] = title;
            NewItem.Update();

          //  NewItem.Update();


            foreach (GridViewRow row in FormDGrid.Rows)
           // for (int count = 0; count < FormDGrid.Rows.Count; count++)
            {
                NewItem["State"] = ((Label)FormDGrid.FindControl("StateField")).Text;
                NewItem["County"] = ((DropDownList)FormDGrid.FindControl("CountyField")).Text;
                NewItem["City or Town"] = ((TextBox)FormDGrid.FindControl("CityField")).Text;
                NewItem.Update();
                List.Update();

            }
```

thoughts? the assignment of Title column works directly but if I try to link to a control within the GridView it fails.

edit: here is the code on the aspcx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State" HeaderStyle-Width="70">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label CssClass="ms-input" Width="70"
   ID="lblState" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "state")%>'   runat='server' />                       
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="County">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="lblCounty" runat="server" CssClass="ms-input"  Width="150">
<asp:ListItem Value="01">--select County here--</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="02">Columbia</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="03">Charleston</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>



<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City or Town" HeaderStyle-Width="270" SortExpression="lll">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox CssClass="ms-input" TextMode="SingleLine" MaxLength="3700" Width="270"
   ID="lblCity" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cityorTown") %>' runat='server' />                       
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Could you post the code on the ascx / aspx page? And if you put the code inside a try catch and print out the exception on the web part / application page, what is the specific error message?

Comment: alright, just posted it up. not sure on your 2nd question, no error gets returned.

Comment: It should be row.FindControl instead of FormDGrid.FindControl, as you are looking for control in row of a grid

Answer (score 0):

You should put the Control's ID inside the FindControl method, such as:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in FormDGrid.Rows)
       // for (int count = 0; count < FormDGrid.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            NewItem["State"] = ((Label)FormDGrid.FindControl("lblState")).Text;
            NewItem["County"] = ((DropDownList)FormDGrid.FindControl("lblCounty")).Text;
            NewItem["City or Town"] = ((TextBox)FormDGrid.FindControl("lblCity")).Text;
            NewItem.Update();
            List.Update();

        }
```